# Using Adafruit RTClib without fragmenting the heap

Tags: c++

I'm getting ready to add DS1307 support to my Arduino app, and was *horrified* when I looked at the sourcecode for the RTC_DS1307 class in Adafruit's RTClib library...

```
DateTime RTC_DS1307::now() {
  uint8_t buffer[7];
  buffer[0] = 0;
  i2c_dev->write_then_read(buffer, 1, buffer, 7);

  return DateTime(bcd2bin(buffer[6]) + 2000U, bcd2bin(buffer[5]),
                  bcd2bin(buffer[4]), bcd2bin(buffer[2]), bcd2bin(buffer[1]),
                  bcd2bin(buffer[0] & 0x7F));
}
```

... and realized that it appears to be instantiating a new throw-away DateTime object on the heap every time you call now()... which AFAIK, is the **ultimate** Arduino C++ taboo.

I was about to tear into the class and rewrite it to reuse a singleton DateTime object that gets created once and reused forever... but then I remembered about return value optimization.

**Is** this actually a scenario where RVO will automagically kick in to save the day and prevent a heap-allocation (by pre-allocating space for the DateTime object on the caller's stack prior to calling `now()`), or is this library indeed doing something as taboo as I think it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a minimal sketch that calls `RTC_DS1307::now()`, disassembled
it, and here is what I saw:

- The caller allocates 6 bytes on the stack for holding the return
  value.
- It writes the address of this stack location in the register pair
  r25:r24, as per the AVR calling convention,<sup>1</sup> then calls
  `RTC_DS1307::now()`.
- As the callee computes the fields of the resulting `DateTime` (by
  means of inlined calls to `bcd2bin()`), it writes them directly into
  the caller's stack frame, with no intermediate copy in RAM.

This looks to me like return value optimization.

**However**, in order to witness this behavior, I had to call
`RTC_DS1307::now()` *twice*. If the method is called from a single place
within the sketch, the compiler inlines it, and there isn't even a
function call to begin with.

Then, of course, the heap is never touched.

<sup>1</sup> *You would expect the `this` pointer to be passed as the
first argument, in r25:r24. It would seem it has been optimized out,
which makes sense given that there is only one `RTC_DS1307` object in
the whole sketch.*

Comment: Surely the heap is never touched in any case?

Comment: `with no intermediate copy in RAM` - using RAM is not the same thing as using the heap.

Comment: @NickGammon: The heap is not touched by `RTC_DS1307::now()`. On AVR, `new` calls `malloc`. Thus, if the heap is ever touched, `avr-nm the_sketch.elf | grep malloc` will show you: `malloc`, `__malloc_heap_start`, `__malloc_heap_end` and `__malloc_margin`.

Comment: I wish I could give points for both answers, but I'm going with Edgar's due to the info about being able to determine with certainty whether the heap is being touched by something. I've been dying to find info about that particular topic for months.

Comment: Edgar Bonet's answers are usually excellent. I think we are in agreement that there is no problem with heap fragmentation in this particular case.

Comment: I wonder how could one assume some heap allocation from the code presented in the question. I guess return of object by copy is not intuitive. Usually the compiler even optimizes it so there is no copying.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing the stack and the heap. For something to appear in the heap you would expect to see the words `new` or `malloc` which I don't see.

What is happening here is that a DateTime object is being created (in the stack frame of the current function) by `RTC_DS1307::now` which is being (presumably) copied into a variable of that type in the caller's stack frame when the function returns.

No memory is being wasted here.

---

> it appears to *literally* be instantiating a new throw-away DateTime object on the heap

What gives you that idea? The heap is not involved without you using `new` or `malloc`.

---

The heap is a block of memory used for dynamic memory allocation by using `malloc` or `new`, generally speaking. Typically it will be allocated past the place in RAM where variables are allocated (ie. after all the variables) and grow upwards, whereas the stack will be allocated at the end of available memory and grow downwards. Thus they don't clash until they collide, either by using too much stack (eg. by recursive function calls) or by allocating too much of the heap (by repeatedly calling `malloc` and without calling `free`).

When you use the heap, by using `malloc` you will get a *pointer* which you can then use, and pass around. That memory which you have reserved is yours until you free it, by literally calling `free`. In C++ something very similar is done by using `new` and `delete`.

If you don't call `malloc` or use `new` then you aren't using the heap, end of story.

Comment: Prior to about an hour ago, I didn't realize there was a mechanism in c++ to create an object on a subroutine/method's stack & atomically copy it to the caller's stack upon return. I thought the called method/subroutine's stack vanished the instant `return` executed, so an object created in & returned by a method/subroutine *had* to either go in the heap or use RVO. Up to now, I always tiptoed around it by doing the 'Android' thing & passing my return-object containers TO methods & reusing them.

Comment: @Bitbang3r Well, yes, you could always pass one by reference.

Comment: @Bitbang3r See amended answer for more explanations about the heap.

Comment: In most cases, thanks to [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) the returned object is constructed in the stack frame of the caller, avoiding the copying step.